# Has anyone learned the Sheiltot of R. Achai Gaon with the Netziv's commentary?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, geonim

Would you recommend it? I really enjoy learning anything with the Netziv and I like the idea of halachic midrashim on the parsha with some ethical messages. It seems like it's a great way to learn major concepts of large halachic topics. It also seems like it might be a great way to really see the values underlying major halachic discussions. I'm a congregational rabbi so I could possibly use some of the material in divrei Torah for my congregation. Is it relatively readable? What does the Netziv's commentary try to accomplish? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Marcus, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get useful answers, and that you also look around for other helpful information around here and contribute more questions and answers! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: How's your Aramaic?

Comment: not bad I regularly learn gemara but certainly not perfect

Comment: IMHO, depends what your goal is: for yourself or for/with the congregation.

Comment: Whoever voted to close because it is primarily opinion based, isn't every product-recommendation question opinion based? Or is that tag reserved for asking for and receiving objective facts.

Comment: @robev, if the question were what is a good Halachic medrash on the parsha with ethical messages, that would be fine. Here it is asking about a product with "relatively reliable" "try to accomplish". It could be made objective (do the halachic views represent the Netziv's halachic opinions, what is the focus of the commentary, stuff like that. But right now, it isn't very objective.